# rtabmap with stereo images

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i used this file [link text](https://gist.github.com/matlabbe/5731ce3b2bc25ec5e0295a80c9f5f671) for create map and localization by stereo images. but when i used parameter (rviz:=true), rtabmapviz and  rviz simultaneous run  and this error is created:
[pcl::VoxelGrid::applyFilter] Leaf size is too small for the input dataset. Integer indices would overflow.

please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279948/rtabmap-with-stereo-images/) by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The warning was coming from `rtabmap_ros/points_xyzrgb nodelet`, caused by the `voxel_size` parameter which was set too small for the stereo point clouds. This is fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/commit/37b85a5c7ad3538746f55fca77f131d240953e05) where `voxel_size` is now disabled by default.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-18**:
how can i solved this problem? Should I update rtabmap_ros package?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2018-01-18**:
You can manually make the change in your installed rtabmap.launch, or copy rtabmap.launch to another location and modify it. No rebuild from source is required as it is a change in a launch file. You can also not subscribe to `voxel_cloud` in RVIZ, then the warning will disappear.

**Comment by [zahra.kh](https://answers.ros.org/users/32216/zahra.kh/) on 2018-01-18**:
thanks, matlabbe